# Adding an aggregate function to the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, where-clause

I want to make a report that tells all the customers that haven't been called in the last 75 or so days. My columns are as follows.

`Customer# Customer_Name Phone_Number Call_Date Salesman`

The call date pulls up the dates of any and every time the customer has been called.

Here's my current query.

```
select customer_no
      ,Customer_name
      ,Phone_number
      ,max(Call_Date) as Call_date
      ,Salesman
from salescalls
where call_date <= current_date - 75
```

The problem I'm having is that it is pulling every single customer and using the last time they were called 75 or more days ago.

For example when the last call date is 6/4/14, it pulls the number up and lists the call date as 11/10/13.

It isn't supposed to list customers that have been called within the last 75 days. So to prevent this, I'm trying to do this in the where clause.

```
Where max(call_date) <= current_date - 75
```

But this just gives me an error:

```
aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause
```

Comment: So many duplicates. Even from today.

Comment: I probably should have put in there that I looked everywhere to find this, but couldn't find an answer that would work.

Comment: The dupe from today even has almost the same title. Have a look at the comments to the dupe.

Comment: You formulated a decent question, that's something. Downvote removed. Still a dupe, though, which we try to avoid.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You want a `having` clause:

```
select customer_no, Customer_name, Phone_number, max(Call_Date) as Call_date,
       Salesman
from salescalls
group by customer_no, Customer_name, Phone_number, Salesman
having max(call_date) <= current_date - 75;
```

You can't put aggregation functions in a `where` clause.

Answer (score 7):

You need to put your condition in [HAVING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/tutorial-agg.html) clause.

```
having max(call_date) <= current_date - 75
```

Comment: Should that replace the where clause?

Comment: yes..move your's condition to having clause, because there is aggregate function in your condition